# Unable to update Notes in react js

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Can anyone help me out with code means how to edit a text in notes
Anyone help me out. I have put all the code and I need the edit code I am not figuring it out
If anyone get the code then please help me out so that I can understand and implement it further Also tell me that I have to prepared new file or editing in this file do the job for me. And if it done in it then how please give me the proper information
Thanks
Ignore from here
contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of
classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin
professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words,
consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical
literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum

**App.jsx**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Header from "./Header";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import Note from "./Note";
import CreateArea from "./CreateArea";

function App() {
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);

  function addNote(newNote) {
    setNotes(prevNotes => {
      return [...prevNotes, newNote];
    });
  }

  function deleteNote(id) {
    setNotes(prevNotes => {
      return prevNotes.filter((noteItem, index) => {
        return index !== id;
      });
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <CreateArea onAdd={addNote} />
      {notes.map((noteItem, index) => {
        return (
          <Note
            key={index}
            id={index}
            title={noteItem.title}
            content={noteItem.content}
            onDelete={deleteNote}
          />
        );
      })}
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Note.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import DeleteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Delete";

function Note(props) {

  function handleClick() {
    props.onDelete(props.id);
  }

  return (
    <div className="note">
      <h1>{props.title}</h1>
      <p>{props.content}</p>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>
        <DeleteIcon />
      </button>
      <button>
        Edit
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Note;
```

**CreateArea.jsx**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import AddIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Add";
import Fab from "@material-ui/core/Fab";
import Zoom from "@material-ui/core/Zoom";

function CreateArea(props) {
  const [isExpanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);

  const [note, setNote] = useState({
    title: "",
    content: ""
  });

  function handleChange(event) {
    const { name, value } = event.target;

    setNote(prevNote => {
      return {
        ...prevNote,
        [name]: value
      };
    });
  }

  function submitNote(event) {
    props.onAdd(note);
    setNote({
      title: "",
      content: ""
    });
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  function expand() {
    setExpanded(true);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form className="create-note">
        {isExpanded && (
          <input
            name="title"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={note.title}
            placeholder="Title"
          />
        )}

        <textarea
          name="content"
          onClick={expand}
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={note.content}
          placeholder="Take a note..."
          rows={isExpanded ? 3 : 1}
        />
        <Zoom in={isExpanded}>
          <Fab onClick={submitNote}>
            <AddIcon />
          </Fab>
        </Zoom>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CreateArea;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the best code but I hope you get the idea here.

In App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
// import Header from "./Header";
// import Footer from "./Footer";
import Note from "./Note";
import CreateArea from "./CreateArea";

function App() {
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);

  function addNote(newNote) {
    setNotes((prevNotes) => {
      return [...prevNotes, newNote];
    });
  }
  function editNote(id,title,content){
    const tobeUpdated = notes.find(singleNote => singleNote.id === id)
    tobeUpdated.id = id
    tobeUpdated.title = title;
    tobeUpdated.content = content;
    setNotes([...notes])

    
  }
  function deleteNote(id) {
    setNotes((prevNotes) => {
      return prevNotes.filter((noteItem) => {
        return noteItem.id !== id;
      });
    });
  }
  console.log(notes);
  return (
    <div>
      <CreateArea onAdd={addNote} />
      {notes.map((noteItem) => {
        return (
          <Note
            key={noteItem.id}
            id={noteItem.id}
            title={noteItem.title}
            content={noteItem.content}
            onDelete={deleteNote}
            onEdit={editNote}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In CreateArea.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
// //import AddIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Add";
// import Fab from "@material-ui/core/Fab";
// import Zoom from "@material-ui/core/Zoom";

function CreateArea(props) {
  const [isExpanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);

  const [note, setNote] = useState({
    id: "",
    title: "",
    content: ""
  });

  function handleChange(event) {
    const { name, value } = event.target;

    setNote((prevNote) => {
      return {
        ...prevNote,
        [name]: value
      };
    });
  }

  function submitNote(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    setNote({
      id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
      title: "",
      content: ""
    });
    props.onAdd(note);
  }

  function expand() {
    setExpanded(true);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form className="create-note">
        {isExpanded && (
          <input
            name="title"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={note.title}
            placeholder="Title"
          />
        )}

        <textarea
          name="content"
          onClick={expand}
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={note.content}
          placeholder="Take a note..."
          rows={isExpanded ? 3 : 1}
        />
        <button onClick={submitNote}>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CreateArea;
```

In Notes.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
//import DeleteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Delete";
import "./styles.css";

function Note(props) {
  const [displayForm, setForm] = useState(false);
  function handleClick() {
    props.onDelete(props.id);
  }
  function handleEdit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const title = e.target.children[0].value;
    const content = e.target.children[1].value;
    props.onEdit(props.id, title, content);
  
    setForm(false)
  }

  return (
    <div className="note">
      <h1>{props.title}</h1>
      <p>{props.content}</p>
      <form
        onSubmit={handleEdit}
        className={`${displayForm ? "show" : "hide"}`}
      >
        <input placeholder="title" />
        <input placeholder="content" />
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>X</button>
      <button onClick={() => setForm(!displayForm)}>Edit</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Note;
```

In styles.css

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
.show{
  display: block;
}
.hide{
  display: none;
}
```

You can try it out here: https://codesandbox.io/s/using-pre-built-react-components-completed-forked-krfy1?file=/src/components/Note.jsx

Comment: I am getting it, but how do I implement this in my code to edit a selected note ? I am new to react so I am not getting it perfectly. Can you tell me where and what code to add in my code which I have shared ? Please It means alot 

Comment: I have updated the answer. You can also try the sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-fog-3okkz?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I have use your logic in my code and get some error 

1. Whenever I add notes, the form for edit is already displayed, It should not happen when I Click edit button then only it should display.
2. While editing the text and submitting it, the text is not updated it is showing error that id is not defined.

You can try it here :

https://codesandbox.io/s/using-pre-built-react-components-completed-forked-ok1xw?file=/src/components/App.jsx

If you get it, then please correct the code and share the link 

Comment: Bro, you need to import css file as well for edit form to show only when you click the button. I have updated your sandbox and it works fine. Consider upvoting my answer if it solves your issue.

Comment: Thank You ! Issue Solved 

Answer (score 0):

Find the item you want to update and just set the new items as you want. You have already implemented the delete feature, this is similar to it. Just find the item you want to edit using id and set the things you want.

Comment: I am not able to do it, can you please share the code with me ?

Comment: Okay I have added an answer. Consider upvoting if it helps you and let me know if you have any other queries.